# How to display programmatically the id from a database using setOnItemClickListener on a ListView

Tags: android, json, final

I have created a ListView in which i want to display some records from a database. This is working fine. I also want when someone clicks an item from the ListView, the correct id and product name to be displayed. In my case, every time i click an item, it displayed only the last record. What can i do to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "productName";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, showProductsUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("products");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                final String productId = jsonObject.getString("id");
                final String productName = jsonObject.getString("productName");
                HashMap<String, String> product = new HashMap<>();
                product.put(ID, productId);
                product.put(PRODUCT_NAME, productName);
                productList.add(product);

                String[] from = {PRODUCT_NAME};
                int[] to = {R.id.productName};

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), productList, R.layout.list_products_to_buy, from, to);

                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        System.out.println(productId + " " + productName);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you define listener in for loop.try to define other place than this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not declare the adapter repeatedly inside the loop.

If you want the ID, you need to add it to the `from` array.

```
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "productName";

String[] from = { ID, PRODUCT_NAME };
int[] to = { R.id.productId,  R.id.productName };

final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(YourActivity.this, productList, R.layout.list_products_to_buy, from, to);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object clicked = adapter.getItem(position); // For example

        // TODO: Somehow extract that data from 'clicked'

        System.out.println(productId + " " + productName);
    }
});

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, showProductsUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("products");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                final String productId = jsonObject.getString("id");
                final String productName = jsonObject.getString("productName");
                HashMap<String, String> product = new HashMap<>();
                product.put(ID, productId);
                product.put(PRODUCT_NAME, productName);
                productList.add(product);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    

    }
}); 

// TODO: Add to Volley request queue
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, i just removed the adapter from inside the loop and it's working better. And now, how can i extract from the `clicked Object` the id and productName? Thanks

Comment: I just solved it. I got the id and productName from the `clicked Object`. Thanks a lot!